# Setting the suspend timeout cross-window manager

Tags: linux, x11, suspend, window-managers, acpi

For a project I'm currently working on, I would like to be able to set the interval after which the operating system (not just the display) goes into standby mode (ACPI s3 or s4). One of the options is to set this in the window manager, but for our project this isn't an option since we would like to support many window managers.

Another option is to use xautolock and pm-suspend to suspend the system ourselves. However, this has two disadvantages: (1) it has a limit of 1 hour and (2) it also triggers if the user is watching a movie.

Are there ways to work around these issues or are there any other methods of setting the standby interval?

Best,
Pul

Comment: FYI I use `xautolock` and it never triggers while `mplayer` is playing.

Answer (score -1):

The screen suspend is not related to the window manager. It is controlled by X. The timeout can be controlled with `xset`, the user preference utility for X. Example:

```
xset +dpms 60 120 180  # standby, suspend, off
```

Comment: Marco, thank you for your quick reply.

Dpms manages the standby-time of a monitor, but what I'm looking for is the standby-time for the entire system (ACPI s3 or s4).